# Controllers separation of concerns in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, backend, crud

I have been working on a project using php with laravel for a week now, I just want to make sure I am following the best practices.

I really like the idea of Resource controllers and CRUD, they make sense and I chose to follow this approach. However, should I be using them on a model where different users have different access rights on it?

**suppose I have different types of users (user, admin, agent) that have different access rights on the same models. Which of the following approaches is more appropriate for this case?**

- Create a normal controller for each user type along with its middleware that authorizes the access to this controller. Then add a route to that controller with that middleware.
- Create a resource controller for each resource (model), create a **route group** for each user type containing all routes for this user type from the defined controllers along with a middleware for this route group.

In other words, where both of the following are possible, should controllers definition be based on user type or resources themselves?

Comment: I just use the same controller and methods for everyone, then check access rights in the method and respond accordingly. But, this is not a good question for SO, too broad and opinion-based.

Comment: Shouldn't access rights be verified in a middleware as a better practice?, It was meant to be like a discussion so we can compare approaches, we might end up with a better approach than ours.

Comment: Isn't this what policies are for? You don't have to check whether the user has access to the entire controller, just check if they can access that particular action: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization

Answer (score 0):

Personally I name my controllers based on the resources and then **handle the roles/user types via middlewares**